# jQuery Validation plugin regex case insensitivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to make my customer method in jQueries Validation to add regex case insensitve however nothing I have tried works.

Code:

```
        $.validator.addMethod(
                "regex",
                function(value, element, regexp) {
                    var re = new RegExp(regexp);
                    return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
                },
                "Please enter valid UK postal code"
        );

        $('form#changePostcode').validate({
            rules: {
                postcode: {
                    required: true,
                    regex: "^(GIR 0AA)|(TDCU 1ZZ)|(ASCN 1ZZ)|(BIQQ 1ZZ)|(BBND 1ZZ)|(FIQQ 1ZZ)|(PCRN 1ZZ)|(STHL 1ZZ)|(SIQQ 1ZZ)|(TKCA 1ZZ)|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]|[A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9]|[ABEHMNPRV-Y]))|[0-9][A-HJKS-UW])\s?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}"
                }
            },
```

I have tried adding `\i` and `\\i` to the end of the regex line but neither has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"i" is used to mention that it must be case insensitive.

```
new RegExp(regexp,"i");
```

or

```
/regexp/i
```

Comment: You just beat me to it! I had just figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Case insensitive regular expressions can be done as:

```
var regex = /hello/i;
```